# JQuery prototyping functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to create a prototype of the ajax object.

I have created these functions:

```
$.extend({
    ajax_prototype : function(parammeters){
        instance = this;
        instance.cache = false;
        instance.crossDomain = false;
        instance.dataType = 'json';
        instance.timeout = 30000;
        instance.error = default_error_function;

        $.each(parammeters,function(key,value){
            instance[key] = value;
        });
    },
    set_ajax_action : function(template,action,func,def){
        template[action] = func;                        
    }
});
```

**ajax_prototype**
Is a constructor for the object.
Sets some default settings and some defined based on every need.

**set_ajax_action**
Sets the function to be executed on each event.

When I create an object like this:

```
temp1 = new $.ajax_prototype({
   'type'           : 'post',
   'url'            : 'controller.php',
});
```

I get this object:

```
Object { cache: false, crossDomain: false, dataType: "json", timeout: 30000, error: default_error_function(), type: "post", url: "controller.php", success: function () }
```

But after I use this:

```
$.set_ajax_action(temp1,'error',function(){console.log();});
```

The object becomes like this:

```
Object { cache: false, crossDomain: false, dataType: "json", timeout: 30000, error: function (), type: "post", url: "controller.php", success: function () }
```

Basicly their difference is the way error function is set.
Both objects work prety good. 
But I would like to make the prototype to create the object with the second form. 
Can someone explain me why the difference on the two objects and how to resolve my problem?

**Edit 1**
I can also create the second object even if I remove the error property from my prototype and call $.set_ajax_action(...) .
My problem is why there is difference to the functions presentation to console.
I know my question is trivial and that either way the result would be the same, but I wan to know how it works.

By the way, even if I set the error property like this:

```
instance.error = function(){ ... };
```

The result will be:

```
Object { cache: false, ifModified: false, processData: true, crossDomain: false, dataType: "json", timeout: 30000, error: .ajax_prototype/instance.error(), url: "test" }
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery.extend? You are not merging any objects with it.

Comment: @Ozan For no apparent reason. I could use plain functions. The result is the same.

Comment: Find definition of your error function, something like `function default_error_function() {...}` and replace it with `var default_error_function = function() {...}`. Will it do what you want?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Everything except set_ajax_action() will return the wrong object.

Comment: I don't understand what "the way error function is set" means.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Please check the error property on both objects. Sorry if I said something the wrong way.

Comment: I don#t understand what "*I would like to make the prototype to create the object with the second form.*" is supposed to mean. Also, your second snippet uses the result of the first snippet, so how do you think you could use one but not the other?

Comment: Okay, now I got it. Can I ask why you care? You know there's absolutely no difference except in console, which tries to make things more understandable when it can.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, you mean with how the function is/isn't displaying? Do you *want* it to display, or *not* want it to display? If you *want* it to, name the anonymous function you send it. If you don't, wrap the default in an anonymous function.

Comment: @DaveNewton in firefox this still isn't that good, it shows `error: .ajax_prototype/instance.error()`. Interestingly, I cannot find a way to make it display just `function()`.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Well, you are right It is completely pointless. I just want to know what is happening why there is difference to the objects.

Comment: Because console can understand whether you are assigning named function (or lambda assigned to variable) or anonymous, and if second, then tries to show where you created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console is able to trace if a function can be identified somehow. For example, if it has a name or it is assigned to variable, console will show its/variable's name. If it's created inside a function, console will show it. Example:

```
(function testt(){
    $.set_ajax_action(temp1,'error',function(){console.log();});
})()
console.log(temp1)
```

this code will produce `error: testt/<()` (firefox).

You can hide name of function, not giving your default handler a name. For example, like this:

```
(function(default_error_function){
    $.extend({
        ajax_prototype : function(parammeters){
            instance = this;
            ...
            instance.error=default_error_function
            ...
        },
        set_ajax_action : ...
    });
})(function() {/* default error handler */})
```

Here, scope of `default_error_function` symbol is not global, therefore console does not show it. At the same time, handler was created outside any other function, so console only has `function ()` to show.